# How to check the string contains the match in PHP

Tags: php, string-matching, http-referer

I have to check that the URL does not contains a string.

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$match1 = "http://myapp.com";
$match2 = "http://www.myapp.com";
```

I want to check that the value in `$url` does not contain either `$match1` and `$match2`. How do I do this?

Comment: I find it interesting that you have over 1000 reputation, but don't know how to format a question.

Comment: Well, Mischa, all people are not good in writing.

Comment: @altafhussain I'm not talking about writing, I'm talking about formatting.

Comment: I find it interesint that you have over 1000 reputation, but don't know how to use google.com

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) in PHP

```
<?php
$yoururlarray=['somewebsite.com','somewebsite2.com'];
$urls=implode(',',$yoururlarray);
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$urls)!==false)
{
    // Found a match so write the ignore code here as you want !
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the referrer string is not always set (browsers may decided not to send it) so don't rely on it for important functionality.

Comment: This is very true. If you add an example of the code the OP wanted , you will get votes too. Nice catch , Pete.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion,matching the string or matching a pattern which contains multiple url forms is what you need think.
such as :

1. http://myapp.com
2. http://myapp.com/
3. http://www.myapp.com
4. http://www.myapp.com/
5. ...

considering all of the situations!

***Note***:HTTP_REFERER can be forged.

so,you may validate it like this:

```
if ($url = filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
   if(!in_array( parse_url($url,PHP_URL_HOST), array('myapp.com','www.myapp.com',...) )){
       // do something
   }
}
```